# where is the default login action in Spring Security 3

Tags: spring, spring-security

```
 when I deploy the Spring Security3 example, helloworld-jc， I find the form submit to a url named /sample/login
```

User:
    Password:

but I can't find where is the login action，anyone know where is the login action in Spring Security3？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default you get an automatic login action (if you don't configure one) created by spring security. You can configure that in your security config (assuming your're going to use xml configuration. For java config the idea is the same but obviously with the java differences) using the tag (using spring security 3.1 and spring security xml schema (http://www.springframework.org/schema/security):

```
<security:form-login login-page="/your_login_page" default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/your_login_page?error" />
```

This inside a security:http tag. Look http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure login flow in spring-security.xml